# Sharing Styles between Sparx Enterprise Architect Projects

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there any obvious way of sharing Styles - as set in the Layout/Style panel (EA13) - between EAPs? Seems like an obvious simple feature that should be in the tool somewhere, but if it is I just can't find it!

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. The best you can do is to extract them from the registry. Unfortunately this is documented nowhere and the used keys are spread all over `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems`.

You might also ask on Sparx' forum and hope for one of the supporters to read and give a better answer or to send a mail to Sparx' support.